# Strings without three consecutive zeros

Tags: combinatorics

How many strings of bits with length 4 don't have three consecutive zeros?

Don't know how to start this one.

Answer (score 3):

There are $16$ such strings, and the only ones with three consecutive zeros are $0000$, $0001$ and $1000$. That leaves $13$.

Comment: How did you infer that OP was talking about only 0's and 1's?

Comment: @Nikunj: It says "strings of bits".

Comment: (+1) I see, I didn't read it **that** carefully!